# using ntile within a group

Tags: r, dplyr, percentile

I'm trying to calculate the quintiles within each group of a dataframe. If I do:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear,carb) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(wt), .groups = "keep") %>%
  mutate(rank = ntile(total,5))
```

All entries within the `rank` column are equal to 1. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Each group has  _only_ one element! Therefore, the rank is always equal to 1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you `group_by(gear, carb)`, unique combinations of these two variables are treated as a group. Since you used `summrise(..., .groups = "keep")`, all grouping variables in the input are preserved. In this case, there's only one unique combinations for these two columns, and therefore, every row would be in it's own group (note `# Groups:   gear, carb [11]` in the `tibble` output). Therefore, you are calculating `ntile` of one element for every group, and the result will of course be 1.

If you don't include the `.groups = "keep"` argument, the last grouping variable will be dropped (`carb` will be dropped), and you can see rank per `gear` (note `# Groups:   gear [3]`).

A little more information in the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) (`?dplyr::summarise`):

> When .groups is not specified, it is chosen based on the number of rows of the results:
>
> - If all the results have 1 row, you get "drop_last".
> - If the number of rows varies, you get "keep".

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear,carb) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(wt)) %>%
  mutate(rank = ntile(total, 5))

# A tibble: 11 × 4
# Groups:   gear [3]
    gear  carb total  rank
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     3     1  9.14     1
 2     3     2 14.2      3
 3     3     3 11.6      2
 4     3     4 23.4      4
 5     4     1  8.29     1
 6     4     2 10.7      2
 7     4     4 12.4      3
 8     5     2  3.65     4
 9     5     4  3.17     2
10     5     6  2.77     1
11     5     8  3.57     3
```