# R: Overlapping Grouped Ntiles?

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

var1 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var2 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var3 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var4 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var5 <- factor(sample(c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))
var6 <- factor(sample(c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))


my_data = data.frame( var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
```

I then used the following code to find out the ntile (e.g. ntile = 4) ranges of "var1" based on "var5" and "var6":

```
test = data.frame(my_data %>%
    group_by(var5, var6) %>%
    mutate(group = ntile(var1, 4)) %>%
    group_by(var5, group) %>%
    mutate(min = min(var1),
           max = max(var1)) %>%
    mutate(range = paste(min, max, sep = "-")) %>%
mutate(count = n()) %>%
    ungroup())
```

I started to inspect these ranges - for example, looking at the first grouping:

```
t = test[test$var5 == "A" & test$var6 == "A",]
table(t$range)

-284.532016946004-41.1223359161037  155.096551597729-439.037082127154  31.8870220096767-101.689288211385  94.4497431366975-175.804225191541 
                               123                                122                                123  

                          122
```

**I noticed some problems here:**

- Some of the ranges are overlapping (e.g. 31 - 101 and 94 - 175)
- The upper bound on one of the ranges is greater than the maximum value of var1 (same issue with the lower bound/minimum value of var1)

E.g.

```
> min(t$var1)
[1] -184.3018
> max(t$var1)
[1] 352.2398
```

**Can someone please show me how to fix my code so I can resolve this problem?**

Thanks!

Reference:

- [using ntile within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076368/using-ntile-within-a-group)

Comment: I.e if you do `group_by(var5, var6, group) %>%`, I get `table(t$range)

-184.301789503408-41.1223359161037  164.320351401576-352.239807042822  41.6359330862004-96.5932746261536  97.4673839365592-162.203323587106 
                               123                                122                                123                                122`

Comment: i.e. try `test <- my_data %>%
    group_by(var5, var6) %>%
    mutate(group = ntile(var1, 4)) %>%
    group_by(var5, var6, group) %>%
    mutate(min = min(var1),
           max = max(var1)) %>%
    mutate(range = paste(min, max, sep = "-")) %>%
mutate(count = n()) %>%
    ungroup()`

Comment: @ akrun: I posted your code below - is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, wouldn't that give the correct frequencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer provided by  @akrun:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

var1 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var2 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var3 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var4 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var5 <- factor(sample(c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))
var6 <- factor(sample(c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))



my_data = data.frame( var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)

test <- my_data %>%     group_by(var5, var6) %>%     mutate(group = ntile(var1, 4)) %>%     group_by(var5, var6, group) %>%     mutate(min = min(var1),            max = max(var1)) %>%     mutate(range = paste(min, max, sep = "-")) %>% mutate(count = n()) %>%     ungroup()


t = test[test$var5 == "A" & test$var6 == "A",]
table(t$range)



-184.301789503408-41.1223359161037  164.320351401576-352.239807042822  41.6359330862004-96.5932746261536  97.4673839365592-162.203323587106 
                               123                                122                                123                                122
```